# how to write an extension for operator?

Tags: swift

For example, write an extension for operator ">" to compare CGSize

```
let sizeA = CGSize(...)
let sizeB = CGSize(...)
sizeA > sizeB // How to let operator ">" support CGSize
```

Comment: Comparing sizes (of rectangles) does not make much sense. Is `(1, 20)` smaller or larger than `(20, 1)` ?

Comment: Perhaps you can clarify when you consider a size to be "larger" than another size, and what you need the  > operator for.

Comment: Thanks guys. I wonder how to make operator do something more. CGSize seems like a meaningless example. Sorry for that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can extend `CGSize` to conform to `Comparable` protocol. @MartinR got the point. I updated my answer to compare the size as area comparison.

```
extension CGSize {
    public static func <(lhs: CGSize, rhs: CGSize) -> Bool {
        return (lhs.width * lhs.height) < (rhs.width * rhs.height)
    }


    public static func >(lhs: CGSize, rhs: CGSize) -> Bool {
        return (lhs.width * lhs.height) > (rhs.width * rhs.height)
    }
}
```

Comment: Conforming to the Comparable protocol *requires*  a "strict total order": For two values a, b exactly one of the relations `a < b`, `b < a` or `a == b` must hold. That is not the case for your implementation.

Comment: Now you override the *existing*  `==(lhs: CGSize, rhs: CGSize)` operator.

Comment: Just looked at the Apple docs again. `CGSize` does conform to the `Equatable` protocol. Edited my answer. Thanks for the catches.

Comment: Now the "strict total order" requirement is violated again, e.g. with a=(1,2) and b=(2,1): None of  a<b, b<a, a==b holds.

Comment: Yeah, that's why I said it's like an area comparison. Otherwise, it does not make sense to compare two `CGSize`.

Comment: My point is: You can define a custom > operator (in any way you like, comparing area or whatever). But a protocol is a *contract* and you must satisfy its requirements when adopting it.

Comment: I got what you mean. In this case, if a=(1,2) and b=(2,1), neither `==` nor `<` is satisfied. As "the  two operations impose a strict total order on the values of a type", it's not conforming to Comparable protocol. On the other hand, if I override the `==`, the Equatable protocol of `CGSize` won't work as it's supposed to be anymore.

Answer (score 2):

Simply define the `>` function for `CGSize`:

```
extension CGSize {
    static func > (_ lhs: CGSize, _ rhs: CGSize) -> Bool {
        // Implement as needed
        return lhs.width > rhs.width && lhs.height > rhs.height
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just to overload the operator **>**

```
extension CGSize{
    static func >(_ left: CGSize, _ right: CGSize)->Bool{
        return left.width*left.height > right.width*right.height
    }
}
```